# Normals not normal?

Tags: rendering, normals

I was modeling a door knob and no matter how many times I recalculated normals, the doorknob renders black. Maybe it's something else but if anybody has suggestions how to fix, it would be greatly appreciated.
Attached is a picture of the knob while rendered.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you share your blend file so we can take a look?

Comment: Sure, I think this link should work, I apologize in advance if the project is a bit "messy", I'm still learning the ropes.    https://www.dropbox.com/s/76qcc4uc511p9u3/LowPolyRoom.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You've given a material to your door knob, with an *Image Texture* node. We don't know how the image looks like as you haven't packed it in the *UV/Image Editor*, but I guess it must be black if you see your door knob black.

[image]